# numba ahead of time compilation of recursive function

Tags: python, recursion, numba

I am trying to compile a recursive function *ahead of time*. As a MCVE, let's take the following function:

```
#import numba as nb
from numba.pycc import CC
cc = CC('precompiled')

#@nb.njit
@cc.export('gsum', 'int64(int64)')
def gsum(n):
    if n>1:
        return n+gsum(n-1)
    else:
        return 1

if __name__== '__main__':
##    print(gsum(5))
    cc.compile()
```

If I run this code, I get the following error trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "numba_ahead.py", line 17, in <module>
    cc.compile()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/compiler_lock.py", line 32, in _acquire_compile_lock
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/pycc/cc.py", line 212, in compile
    objects, dll_exports = self._compile_object_files(build_dir)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/compiler_lock.py", line 32, in _acquire_compile_lock
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/pycc/cc.py", line 200, in _compile_object_files
    compiler.write_native_object(temp_obj, wrap=True)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/pycc/compiler.py", line 198, in write_native_object
    library = self._cull_exports()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/compiler_lock.py", line 32, in _acquire_compile_lock
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/pycc/compiler.py", line 157, in _cull_exports
    locals={}, library=library)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 904, in compile_extra
    return pipeline.compile_extra(func)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 367, in compile_extra
    return self._compile_bytecode()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 835, in _compile_bytecode
    return self._compile_core()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 822, in _compile_core
    res = pm.run(self.status)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/compiler_lock.py", line 32, in _acquire_compile_lock
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 253, in run
    raise patched_exception
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 244, in run
    stage()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 477, in stage_nopython_frontend
    self.locals)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 1005, in type_inference_stage
    infer.build_constraint()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/typeinfer.py", line 816, in build_constraint
    self.constrain_statement(inst)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/typeinfer.py", line 1016, in constrain_statement
    self.typeof_assign(inst)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/typeinfer.py", line 1079, in typeof_assign
    self.typeof_global(inst, inst.target, value)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/typeinfer.py", line 1177, in typeof_global
    typ = self.resolve_value_type(inst, gvar.value)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/typeinfer.py", line 1100, in resolve_value_type
    raise TypingError(msg, loc=inst.loc)
numba.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Untyped global name 'gsum': cannot determine Numba type of <class 'function'>

File "numba_ahead.py", line 9:
def gsum(n):
    <source elided>
    if n>1:
        return n+gsum(n-1)
        ^
```

So apparently `cc.export` doesn't know the type of the function it is compiling, if that function calls itself. Is there any way to fix the problem? When I compile the same code *just in time* with `njit` (commented-out lines) the code compiles just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that when using `numba`sometimes simply changing the way I do particular loops and calculations can fix these issues.  In your case `gsum` below works:

```py
#import numba as nb
from numba.pycc import CC
cc = CC('precompiled')

#@nb.njit
@cc.export('gsum', 'int64(int64)')
def gsum(n):
    run=True
    sm=n
    while n:
        n=n-1
        sm+=n
    return sm


def slow_gsum(n):
    run=True
    sm=n
    while n:
        n=n-1
        sm+=n
    return sm

def slow_gsum2(n):
    if n>1:
        return n+slow_gsum2(n-1)
    else:
        return 1


cc.compile()
```

You can test it like so:

```py
import precompiled
N=1e2
%time out1=precompiled.gsum(N)
%time out2=slow_gsum(N)
%time out3=slow_gsum2(N)
out1==out2,out1==out3,out1

"""output:
CPU times: user 6 µs, sys: 0 ns, total: 6 µs
Wall time: 11 µs
CPU times: user 12 µs, sys: 1e+03 ns, total: 13 µs
Wall time: 15 µs
CPU times: user 44 µs, sys: 1e+03 ns, total: 45 µs
Wall time: 48.9 µs
(True, True, 5050)
"""
```

Here I set `N=1e2` so we could test against your recursive solution (going higher gives a max-recursion error).  You can really see the `numba` speed up by going to higher values of `N`:

```py
N=1e8
%time out1=precompiled.gsum(N)
%time out2=slow_gsum(N)
out1==out2,out1

"""output:
CPU times: user 7 µs, sys: 1e+03 ns, total: 8 µs
Wall time: 11 µs
CPU times: user 6.14 s, sys: 10.9 ms, total: 6.15 s
Wall time: 6.16 s
(True, 5000000050000000)
"""
```

Comment: Converting my function from recursive to iterative was what I eventually settled for. I would, however, have liked to to avoid that as in my case doing it iteratively meant a lot of extra book keeping (the gsum function was just the simplest example I could come up with to demonstrate the problem).